# Can't regroup an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I do a simple explorer on Angular (there are a list of directories that contain other directories or text files). The question is: I receive the following data from the server ("path" is the path of the folder, ids of parent directories):

```js
[
  {
    id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",
    name: "sec list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
  }, 
  {
    id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",
    name: "In aeroport",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",
    name: "Delete",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",
    name: "Aeroport list",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",
    name: "Bordery words",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0"],
  },
  {
    id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",
    name: "mail list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
  }
];
```

How can I regroup that into code below? I know recursion is needed, but I can not understand, how to do it right. Help me, please.

```js
[
      {
        id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",
        name: "In aeroport",
        children: [
          {
            id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",
            name: "Bordery words",
            children: [
              {
                id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",
                name: "sec list",
              },
              {
                id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",
                name: "mail list",
              }
            ],
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",
        name: "Delete",
      },
      {
        id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",
        name: "Aeroport list",
      },
    ]
```

Comment: This is a good leet code question :). Could you post what you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple DFS solves the problem, but there are multiple ways to do this. One way is below

```js
var paths = [
  {
    id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",
    name: "sec list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
  }, 
  {
    id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",
    name: "In aeroport",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",
    name: "Delete",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",
    name: "Aeroport list",
    path: [""],
  },
  {
    id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",
    name: "Bordery words",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0"],
  },
  {
    id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",
    name: "mail list",
    path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],
  }
];


var dfs = function( parentJson , path){
  for(var i=0;i<paths.length;i++){
    if(paths[i].path.join("") == path ){
      var child = {id:paths[i].id,name:paths[i].name,children:[]}
      parentJson.push(child)
      dfs(child.children,path+paths[i].id)
    }
  }
  
}

var json = [];
dfs(json,"")

console.log(json)
```

Comment: I think its DFS traversal

Comment: Note that here you have `children: []` in the output, unlike the OP's desired output. Also, it is not very efficient, as for every node you add, you iterate the input array. That does not make it very scalable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two phases:

First make a nested object structure where the `children` properties are not arrays, but objects, where the object keys are the `id` values. That way you can quickly navigate in that structure with a given path, and extend/deepen it at the same time.

In a final phase, you can use recursion to walk through that tree structure to convert those `children` properties to arrays.

Here is how that looks:

```js
function makeTree(data) {
    // drill down the object structure, where children properties 
    // are nested objects with id values as keys.
    let result = {}; // root of the tree data structure
    for (let {id, name, path} of data) {
        Object.assign(path.slice(1).concat(id).reduce((acc, key) => {
            if (!acc.children) acc.children = {};
            if (!acc.children[key]) acc.children[key] = {};
            return acc.children[key];
        }, result), { id, name });
    }

    return (function unkey(node) {
        // Convert children objects to arrays
        if (node.children) node.children = Object.values(node.children).map(unkey);
        return node;
    })(result);
}

let data = [{id: "6np5E3yyEISXLNX9muyt",name: "sec list",path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],},{id: "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0",name: "In aeroport",path: [""],},{id: "H6AvpwXc49v4oDRWSjym",name: "Delete",path: [""],},{id: "LQ73vVoTuw9xd40jMs3j",name: "Aeroport list",path: [""],},{id: "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV",name: "Bordery words",path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0"],},{id: "jWeClRAw55Er8z0Ow9uq",name: "mail list",path: ["", "GnBOclNO1v3n9FW7aGv0", "X5YNJ6Vco2BtGxNZVsYV"],}];
console.log(makeTree(data));
```

Note that the first value of the `path` value is never used. It seems to always be the empty string.